# Inputting a data file into a module

Tags: scoping, input

I'm currently writing a module that converts a data source into a distance matrix. So far, the code I have works:

```
dataToMatrix[nodeCount_, destNode_] := Module[
   {data, line, row, column, 
    cost},(*These are the local variables used in the module*)
   
   data = 
    Drop[
     Import[
      "graph.txt", "Data"], 0, 
     1]; (*Import the data and remove the first column, 
   since this is just the node and not the destination/costs*)
   
   data = 
    data /. 
      str_String :> StringReplace[StringSplit@str, "node" -> ""] // 
     ToExpression; (*Make the data more mathematica-friendly*)
   
   Q = Table[Infinity, nodeCount, nodeCount];(*Placeholder matrix, 
   where we initially assume all distances are infinite*)
   
   For[i = 1, i <= 99, i++,
    line = data[[i]];
    row = i;
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[line], j++,
     column = line[[j, 1]] + 1;
     cost = line[[j, 2]];
     Q[[row, column]] = cost;]];
   Q[[destNode + 1, destNode + 1]] = 0;
   Q // MatrixForm];
```

However, so that this module can be used on other data sets, I want to make it so you input the data set in the module, rather than it being pre-set in the text. I thought about doing:

```
dataToMatrix[in_File,nodeCount_,destNode_]:=
```

but that doesn't seem to work as the data source needs to be in "".

Any help would be much appreciated! TIA.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Use filename as a parameter to your function/module (instead of a ``File`` object): ``dataToMatrix[filename_, nodeCount_, destNode_] := Module[{...}, ... Import[filename, "Data"] ...]``. Then this can be called by ``dataToMatrix["graph.txt", ...]``.

Comment: That's worked!! Thank you :)